# IE9 border issue (a kind of gradient on top and bottom)

Tags: css, windows-7, internet-explorer-9

I've updated my IE to IE9 and I've noticed the borders everywhere are not been rendered as well. I don't really not how to explain it.

Using Chrome, Firefox, Opera or Safari on this page - http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp - I can see the borders very well, but on IE9 I see those as the image.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tr24r.png

I've been researching a little about it, but seems no one else has a similar problem :( Any idea why this could be happening? On other PC's (friends, office) I don't see this problem on IE9, may be something wrong in my settings?

Window 7
Internet Explorer 9.0.8112.16421

Thanks in advance,
Regards.

Comment: as @unclenorton said, it could be a graphic card's problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to *Settings (Gear icon) -> Internet Options -> Advanced* tab. The first item in the list will be the checkbox entitled *Use software rendering*. Check (or un-check, if it is already checked) it, restart IE and see if there is any difference.

If it helps, try updating your graphics card driver and re-enabling hardware acceleration in IE.

Comment: I have the IE9 in Spanish, so I'm not sure if the option I checked is the same you were talking about. The group is entitled as "Accelerated graphics" (could it be the right translation?) and the option is "Use processing by Software instead of processing by GPU *". As I see, maybe it's a problem on my graphic card :(, it was repaired so time ago, and I think the problem comes from it. I also see a green little line at the bottom of my screen btw, so it might be. HP dv2500... always have problems with Video. Thanks a lot @unclenorton!!! I'm a CSS coder, so it was a BIG help! Much appreciated.

Comment: Yes, we are talking about the same option. Glad it helped.